# Пропал звук во всех Unity проектах

Tags: unity3d, аудио

Для удобства я создал пустую сцену в которой нет ничего кроме камеры и света и добавил к камере компонент AudioSource как на скриншоте.
Audio clip рабочий, он воспроизводится из папки ассетов, но в самой сцене тишина.

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.
Global Volume проекта выставлено на 1.
Версия Unity: 2018.1.1f1
Если собрать готовый проект то все звуки воспроизводятся, следовательно проблема в самом editor-е. Может я мог как-то случайно отключить его или это баг?

[image: Скриншот AudioSource]

Comment: что за гениальный вопрос-ответ? xd

Answer (score 4):

Разумеется это никакие не баги, просто в редакторе есть маленькая незаметная менюшка. Может кому-то поможет этот скрин.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]